# python re.split :how to drop '.'

Tags: python, regex

Here is my example:

```
   In [65]: text = 'Plant.Plant,Plant,update,seedId,Plant,update,status'
   In [66]: pattern = r"(?u)\b\w\w+\b"
   In [67]: import re
   In [68]: re.split(pattern,text)
   Out[68]: ['', '.', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', '']
                  ^
```

How should I to change the pattern which can get:

```
  ['', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', '']
```

The first and the last element of this list is '', and the other element is ',', but the pattern of your solution will get all element is ''.

Answer (score 2):

You may add an optional non-capturing group matching 0+ occurrences of dot(s) followed with 1+ word chars:

```
import re
text = 'Plant.Plant,Plant,update,seedId,Plant,update,status'
pattern = r"(?u)\b\w{2,}(?:\.+\w{2,})*\b"
print(re.split(pattern,text)) # => ['', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', '']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/IKpcBQ) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DKExaV/1).

**Details**

- `(?u)` - an inline `re.UNICODE` modifier
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\w{2,}` - 2 or more word chars (**if you only need letters, use `[^\W\d_]{2,}`**)
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group matching 0+ occurrences of...

  - `\.+` - 1+ dots
  - `\w{2,}` - 2 or more word chars
- `)*` - end of the group
- `\b` - word boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern

`pattern = r"(?u)\b\w?.\w+\b"`

Comment: In [108]: pattern = r"(?u)\b\w?.\w+\b"
In [109]: re.split(pattern,text)
Out[109]: ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

Comment: thanks for your help, but it seems not right.

Comment: what's wrong in this ? can u plz specify

Comment: the result I prefer is ['', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ''], the first and the last element of this list is '', and the other element is ',', but the pattern of your solution will get all element is ''.